# Do you know why mysql fails creating this table?

Tags: mysql

maybe my question is silly... but i couln't found the problem, when i do:

```
CREATE TABLE prefixes (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
INDEX id (id)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Mysql says:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'sms.prefixes' (errno: 150)
```

i though that an old foreign key or something is pointing/using this table, but i did an export (complete) and searched in the export for the key "prefixes" and i found nothing, so no foreign key problem or something, if i create the same table BUT naming it "prefixes2" or some else IT WORKS!!!
Please if someone have any clue maybe it can be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sms.prefixes` (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id), 
INDEX id (id)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9e24)

Comment: Thank you very much for help me, i tried exactly as you said but no luck, i show you the error:

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'sms.prefixes' (errno: 150)
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------------+
| VERSION()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.5.38-0+wheezy1-log |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

Comment: if i change the name it works, maybe it can't be escaped or something, i look everywhere in the database for the word "prefixes" but nothing, no references or something, this is getting weird hehe :)

Comment: @mzalazar:- Updated my answer. I am not sure but looks like you are trying to create table `sms.prefixes` not `prefixes`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, i tried exactly as you write in sqlfiddle, but no luck, my database is called "sms", but i write as you said and it throwed the same error =( now i'm getting a knife and preparing to cut my b*lls hehe :P

Comment: @mzalazar:- Check if the user with which you are trying to create the table has the permission to create. Most likely that issue is there, ie., your user doesnot have the create table permission!

Comment: @mzalazar:- You can use `SHOW GRANTS [FOR user]` to check  the permission for the user.

Comment: No privileges issue (ALL PRIVILEGES, very sure about that), i created a new database (named qq) and tried this script and it worked!, but for some reason fails in this database, any other clue? :-|

Comment: The script is OK, but it seems like name "prefixes" is colliding somewhere.

Comment: @mzalazar:- Was this table present earlier in the database? I mean did you dropped it and trying to create again?

Comment: as i said before, i did an export of the entire database (using --no-data parameter) and searched for "prefixes" but nothing found.

Comment: Yes, i had a table named like that a couple of months ago, but i removed it.

Comment: @mzalazar:- There you go. So I think there are some references present for this table. You need to drop them too before creating it again!

Comment: ok, i will do a "deep search" everywhere and write here if i found anything, thanks!

Comment: @mzalazar:- Try to execute this `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` before you create the table. And see if you get the result

Comment: I tried that before posting here :P and i had tried again but no luck, im searching a way to enumerate all tables/indexes/foreign keys (other way more "deeper" than exporting entire database)

Comment: I think it has something to do with foreign keys, because if i change InnoDB to MyIsam it works. Still searching the issue.

Comment: @mzalazar:- Yes thats what even I think. Thanks!

Comment: @mzalazar:- My last throw...probably because of the reason explained in the architecture here in this answer. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69656/cant-create-table-but-table-doesnt-exist

Comment: Thanks for the link, i read it and is useful, but i don't want to spend more time with it... i needed to create it and i did (changing the engine to MyISAM) :)
Thank you very much!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

but i can't find any foreign key pointing (or named) "prefixes" or something similar, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: And there's no INDEX in the entire database that could collide with "prefixes" or something like that, i checked out. i think i need to change InnoDB for MyISAM to solve this strange problem, i don't see other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Well... i created the table `prefixes` using MyISAM engine, i nad no luck using InnoDB and there's no references to old table, still wondering what could be happening. This is one big reason that i dislike MySQL, and make me love (even more) to PostgreSQL :D